# C++ use Smart Pointers with changing pointer values

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Consider a C library that defines functions for creating, destroying and working with a custom structure

```
struct Foo;
void foo_action(Foo*);
Foo* foo_create();
void foo_free(Foo*);
```

Currently, I used the library in my C++ project as follows

```
Foo* myfoo = foo_create();
foo_action(myfoo);
foo_free(myfoo);
```

I understand why smart pointers are important and want to migrate my code to use them.
That's how the code looks now.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
typedef std::unique_ptr<Foo, std::function<void(Foo*)>> FooPtr;
// ...
FooPtr myfoo2(foo_create(), foo_free);
foo_action(myfoo2.get());
```

It seems to work, but the `myfoo2.get()` invocation seems hacky. **Am I using it as intended?**

There's another part of the library which creates and works with some kind of list structure. The api looks like

```
struct Bar;
Bar* bar_append(Bar*, int);
void bar_free_recursive(Bar*);
```

and is used as

```
// using NULL as current Bar* creates the initial structure
Bar* bar = bar_append(NULL, 1);
// each invocation leads to another 'head' structure
bar = bar_append(bar, 42);
bar = bar_append(bar, 123);
```

As the pointer (the address pointed to) changes with each `bar_append` invocation, how would I introduce smart pointers here, so that `bar_free_recursive` is invoked on the current pointer value when the pointer instance is freed?

Comment: Remember that you can *overload* functions. Why not create a simple inline overloaded `foo_action` function that takes a `FooPtr` argument, and just calls the old `foo_action` function with the raw non-smart pointer? You can still keep the old code, while making the interface nicer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good point, thanks. I just wasn't sure if it is required at all, or if there's a more straigtforward way for the conversion.

Comment: @muffel If you're using modern C++, then you should be using `using` instead of `typedef`.

Comment: Using `std::function` as your *deleter* will be less efficient that crafting a specific *deleter*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think `foo_action` should be specific to a particular kind of smart pointer if it is not taking ownership. I suspect that `foo_action` should probably take a `Foo&` and then the calling code is just `*myfoo2` regardless of the pointer type.

Comment: If you don't like `myfoo2.get()`, you can use `&*myfoo2` instead. That does look a bit hacky, though.

Comment: There [is a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0653r0.html) for `to_address` that would be a generic way of converting a pointer-like object to a pointer that you could perhaps consider using instead of `.get`, at least in generic code.

Comment: No one seems to have explained why using your own deleter is more efficient than using `std::function` or a function pointer. It's because using `std::function` or a function pointer requires `std::unique_ptr` to store the deleter; it's set at runtime. So `sizeof(std::unique_ptr<T>)` would no longer be `T*`. Also, one of the magic properties of `std::unique_ptr` is that the compiler is often able to optimize it away. It would be harder for the compiler to inline the `std::function` or function pointer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> but the myfoo2.get() invocation seems hacky. Am I using it as intended?

It is not hacky, you use it as intended.

I would go one step further and wrap the whole in a class:

```
struct Foo;
void foo_action(Foo*);
Foo* foo_create();
void foo_free(Foo*);

class FooWrapper
{
public:
    FooWrapper() : mFoo(foo_create()) {}

    void action() { foo_action(mFoo.get()); }
private:
    struct FooDeleter
    {
        void operator()(Foo* foo) const { foo_free(foo); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Foo, FooDeleter> mFoo;
};
```

In the same way:

```
struct Bar;
Bar* bar_append(Bar*, int);
void bar_free_recursive(Bar*);

class BarWrapper
{
public:
    explicit BarWrapper(int n) : mBar(bar_append(nullptr, n)) {}

    void append(int n) { mBar.reset(bar_append(mBar.release(), n)); }

private:
    struct BarDeleter
    {
        void operator()(Bar* bar) const { bar_free_recursive(bar); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Bar, BarDeleter> mBar;
};
```

Comment: Added bonus: you only need to `#include <Foo.h>` in `FooWrapper.cpp` and `#include <Bar.h>` in `BarWrapper.cpp` if you follow the normal "member functions only declared in the header" style

Comment: If you already wrap it with a class, why unique pointer?  just make a destructor which calls `foo_free`

Comment: @DavidHaim: Rule of 5/3/0. With your suggestion, I would have to write destructor, move constructor/assignment.

Comment: I would split the reset/release code in `append` up a bit myself.  I'd be too worried about a mixture of exceptions and order of evaluation causing strange corner cases to make that code invalid.  Far too many people have created UB by reading and writing a variable on the same line for me to treat such lines with confidence, either reading or writing it.

Comment: Note that in C++17, you can write `template<auto x> using value_t = std::integral_constant< std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x >;`, and then `BarDeleter` is just `value_t<bar_free_recursive>` and `FooDeleter` is `value_t<foo_free>`.

Comment: If you do this a lot, I might be inclined to wrap `unique_ptr` with a template whose arguments are `<T, void(*)(T*)>`, so you could pass the delete function as a template argument.

Answer (score 5):

Having to write `.get()` is an unfortunate consequence of using smart pointers but I think best practice if you want to pass to a function that accepts a non-owning, nullable pointer.

But, in practice I often find you don't need it to be nullable and can accept a reference instead of a raw-pointer. Then the syntax is a bit less "hacky":

```
void foo_action(Foo&);  // accept a reference instead of a raw-pointer

struct FooDeleter {
    void operator()(Foo* foo) const { foo_free(foo); }
};

using FooPtr = std::unique_ptr<Foo, FooDeleter>;

FooPtr make_foo() {
  return FooPtr(foo_create());
}

int main() {
    auto foo = make_foo();

    // ...  

    if (foo) {             // check for null
        foo_action(*foo);  // dereference smart-pointer
    } 
}
```

`bar_append` should work with a `unique_ptr` providing you use `std::move`:

```
struct BarDeleter {
    void operator()(Bar* bar) const { bar_free_recursive(bar); }
};

using BarPtr = std::unique_ptr<Bar, BarDeleter>;

BarPtr bar_append(BarPtr bar, int value) {
    return BarPtr(bar_append(bar.release(), value));
}

int main() {      
  BarPtr bar;
  bar = bar_append(std::move(bar), 42);
  bar = bar_append(std::move(bar), 123);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would say `myfoo2.get()` is *clunky*, not *hacky*.

I would personally create a template based wrapper `obj_ptr` (you choose a more relevant name) and use traits for each type of object to model your requirement the C++ way. The wrapper can then remove the clunkyness of accessing the underlying object.

```
template <typename T, typename Traits>
class obj_ptr final
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, void(*)(T*)> ptr_{ Traits::create(), Traits::free };

public:
    operator T*() { return ptr_.get(); }

    operator const T*() const { return ptr_.get(); }

    T* operator->() { return ptr_.get(); }

    const T* operator->() const { return ptr_.get(); }
};

class foo_traits
{
public:
    static Foo* create() { return foo_create(); }

    static void free(Foo* foo) { foo_free(foo); }
};

int main()
{
    using FooPtr2 = obj_ptr<Foo, foo_traits>;

    FooPtr2 myfoo2;

    foo_action(myfoo2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```